# Char* is behaving weird (changing value in progress)

Tags: c

Variables:

```
struct configSetting {
    char *value;
};
char *stringResult;
char str[255];
int intResult;
int *p_intResult;
int i = 0;
p_intResult = &intResult;
```

I am converting an int into a string:

```
struct configSetting settings[NUMBEROFSETTINGS];
settings[i].value = itoa(intResult, str, 10);
```

printf prints the correct value into the console:

```
printf("\nVALUE: %s", settings[i].value);
```

After that I am writing the value in another function into the console, the output changes between those two printf:

```
printf("\nTEST 1: %s;%i", settings[15].value, strlen(settings[15].value));
printf("\nTEST 2: %s;%i", settings[15].value, strlen(settings[15].value));
```

That's the result in the console:
TEST 1: 50;2
TEST 2: ý³↑;3

So the char* in settings[15].value is changing between the printf's and I have no idea why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `NUMBEROFSETTINGS`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overwriting the last value of your `itoa()` with the subsequent invoke.

This call:

```
settings[i].value = itoa(intResult, str, 10);
```

is using the variable `str[]`. Each time you do this you overwrite the last results. Further, if `str[]` is local and `settings` is global, the resulting pointers stored are no longer valid, and it is undefined behavior.

Either dynamically allocate the value string with `malloc()` or `strdup()` or some such, or change this:

```
struct configSetting {
    char *value;
};
```

To include a real buffer, like this:

```
struct configSetting {
    char value[64];
};
```

And then just `itoa()` directly to the setting:

```
itoa(intResult, settings[i].value, 10);
```

Comment: woah, thanks for that quick answer, that was totally the problem --> settings[i].value = strdup(itoa(intResult, str, 10)); works now!

Comment: @kaljak Don't forget, `strdup()` is a malloc() in disguise. Be sure to free those when you no longer need them.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same `str` buffer and store a reference to it (`settings[i].value = itoa(intResult, str, 10);`) for every value converted. Next call to `itoa` will overwrite old value.